# Passing variables from views.py into script.js

Tags: javascript, django, django-views, render-to-response

I was wondering whether or not it was possible to pass variables from render_to_response in views.py into script.js,

```
render_to_response('appname/basic.html',{'var':somevariable})
```

I basically want to access the variable {{var}} outside of the HTML page since my script.js uses something like:

```
function WillHappen()
{
    var n = noty({
        text: 'You're {{var}}!',
        type: 'warning',
        dismissQueue: false,
        layout: 'center',
        theme: 'defaultTheme'
    })

}
```

It works if I put the Javascript into the HTML page but I wanted to separate them since I  might be using it in a lot of my HTML pages.

Comment: In that case, how would you suggest I do it? All I want is to display what {{var}} contains in a separate Javascript file which is usually an integer of some sort.

Comment: In your template: `<input id="myhiddenvar" type="hidden">{{ var }}</input>`. Then in your javascript `var text = document.getElementById("myhiddenvar");`

Comment: Have a look at the [HTML5 data tag](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/), which is nice if you don't want to end up with a lot of ids and classes (mixin style hooks and data identifiers)

Comment: @Hedde Yeah, great tip! :) I normally assume that there aren't many who uses HTML5 stuff yet and refrain from using it in answers.

Comment: You can define a global js variable in your template and acces to it into your your script file. `<script> var myVar = '{{ var }}'; </script>` and in your script.js `text: "You're "+myVar+" !"`

Answer (score 0):

A no good solution is writing your code between `<script></script>` in a html file

maybe in a `my_script.html`:

```
<script>
    function WillHappen()
    {
        var n = noty({
            text: 'You're {{var}}!',
            type: 'warning',
            dismissQueue: false,
            layout: 'center',
            theme: 'defaultTheme'
        })

    }
</script>
```

But, is this good?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could have all the variables inside a script tag, and access them through other javascript files such as:

```
<script>
var test = {{var}} || false;
</script>
```

And inside other js files:

```
if (window.test) {
//
}
```